# A* Search Modification

Tags: algorithm, search, graph

The [Wikipedia listing for A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) states:

> In other words, the closed set can be omitted (yielding a tree search algorithm) if a solution is guaranteed to exist, or if the algorithm is adapted so that new nodes are added to the open set only if they have a lower *f* value than at any previous iteration.

However, in doing so, I have found that I receive erroneous results in an otherwise functional A* search implementation. Can someone shed some light on how one would make this modification?

Comment: If I understand what you have written, you have a problem with a monotonic heuristic that is revisiting closed nodes? If so, please provide an example that demonstrates this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your heuristic meets the following:

h(x) <= d(x,y) + h(y)

which means that your heuristic function should not overestimate the cost of getting from your current location to the destination or goal.

For example, if you are in a grid and you are trying to get from A to B, both points on this grid. A good heuristic function is the Euclidean distance between current location and goal:

h(x) = sqrt[ (crtX -goalX)^2 + (crtY -goalY)^2 ]

This heuristic does not overestimate because of the triangle inequality.

More on triangle inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

More on Euclidean distance: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Distance.html